Disable Responsiveness on WordPress Dashboard
I’m working on a project for a client who has some specific requests related to the WordPress admin dashboard. The client accesses the WordPress dashboard via a browser (not the app) and it's RTL. Here’s a detailed list of the issues and attempted solutions so far:
1. Disable Responsive Design for the WordPress Admin Dashboard
The client wants to disable the responsive design for the dashboard only (not the site itself), so it appears the same on mobile as it does on desktop.
My Attempts:
Quick Solution: Used the "Request Desktop Site" feature available in browsers. However, this isn’t practical as editors have to enable it repeatedly.
Slow Solution: Downloaded the dashboard.css file, removed all the media queries, and loaded it with this code:
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', function () {
    // Deregister original styles
    wp_deregister_style('dashboard');
    wp_deregister_style('dashboard-rtl');

    // Enqueue custom styles
    wp_enqueue_style('dashboard', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/custom/custom-dashboard.css', [], null);
    wp_enqueue_style('dashboard-min', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/custom/custom-dashboard.min.css', [], null);
    wp_enqueue_style('dashboard-rtl', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/custom/custom-dashboard-rtl.css', [], null);
    wp_enqueue_style('dashboard-rtl-min', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/custom/custom-dashboard-rtl.min.css', [], null);
});

Unfortunately, this didn’t work as intended.
2. Redirect Dashboard to the "All Posts" Page
The client wants the dashboard to automatically redirect to the "All Posts" page (edit.php) after logging in or after pressing the Publish or Update button when editing a post.
Attempts so far:
I’ve tried various hooks like login_redirect and others, but I couldn’t get it to work for the Publish/Update action.
3. Text Cutting Issue
When I attempt to cut text (on mobile), it actually copies the text instead of cutting it. Additionally, it removes the last letter of the selected text during the process.
Troubleshooting steps taken:
Disabled all custom code in functions.php.
Deactivated all plugins.
Issue persists even in this clean state.
4. Unable to Type in the Title Field
When using "Request Desktop Site" in the mobile browser, I can paste text into the Title Field, but I cannot type directly in it.
I would appreciate any guidance or solutions for these issues.
Thank you so much

this question is in fact multiple question then you have to create one "stackexchange question" per question.

for the first question responsiveness is a sum of lots of responsive effects then you have to list them and customise them one after the other.

could you please clarify more on the "stackexchange question" more?
and more details

after your last edit, you have now 4 questions here then you have to ask each question separately. each question should focus on one problem only.

Some of these are big/deep questions. There's too much here to give a solid answer to all of them at once. Would you mind opening another three questions and cut+ptaste each heading (with whatever intro you need) to separate questions?
